# Unable to apply Kafka Timestamp transform twice on a field

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My `debezium source connector` produces timestamp field in different formats (same column) to kafka.

Example:-

1. "2023-02-26T18:30:00Z"
2. "2022-10-27T09:21:45.522779Z"

So I want to apply the `Kafka-TimestampConverter` twice (since there are two formats of dates in the same field) on the same field in my `kafka sink connector`.  But the sink connector applies only the first transform. The second transform is not applied on the field. Below is the transform

```
"transforms.tscreatedon.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.tscreatedon.field": "created_on",
"transforms.tscreatedon.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'",
"transforms.tscreatedon.target.type": "Timestamp",
"transforms.tscreatedon2.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
"transforms.tscreatedon2.field": "created_on",
"transforms.tscreatedon2.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
"transforms.tscreatedon2.target.type": "Timestamp",
```

Where am I going wrong? How to achieve both transforms?

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
"transforms": "tscreatedon,tscreatedon2"
```

However, after the timestamp is converted once, it may no longer be in the format needed by the second converter.

In other words, `created_on` cannot possibly be two formats at the  same time.

If you are wanting to try-catch a series of possible timestamp conversions, then you would need to write your own transform, or handle that conversion elsewhere, like ksqlDB `COALESCE`, or Kafka Streams.